# JQuery: how to remove all div elements except first containing sub-string as 'id' tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few div elements having id as 'name_a_1', 'name_a_2', 'name_b_3' so on. I want to remove all divs except the first name, which starts from 'name_a_' using JQuery or plain JS?

I successfully tried accessing first and last elements by following JQuery, but how can I access all elements except first?

```
$('[id^="name_a_"]').first()
$('[id^="name_a_"]').last()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use combination [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to target all element except first.

```
$('[id^="name_a_"]:not(:first)').remove()
```

or, [`:gt(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector

> Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```
$('[id^="name_a_"]:gt(0)').remove()
```

---

To check if element have value, `.filter()` can be used

```
var hasValue = $('[id^="name_a_"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).val().trim() !== '';
}).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Plain JS example using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get all matching elements except for the first.

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="name_a_"]'), 1)
    .forEach(elt => elt.parentNode.removeChild(elt))
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="name_a_1">name_a_1</li>
<li id="name_a_2">name_a_2</li>
<li id="name_a_3">name_a_3</li>
<li id="name_a_4">name_a_4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`.not`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the first div:

```
$('div[id^=name_a]').not(':eq(0)').remove();
```